# Any differences between 3 ways of dependency injection?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Is the 3rd one most common way to inject a bean? Any differences between them?

1. Bean constructor parameter injection:

   ```
    public class Checkout {
       private final ShoppingCart cart;

       @Inject
       public Checkout(ShoppingCart cart) {
         this.cart = cart;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Initializer method parameter injection:

   ```
   public class Checkout {

      private ShoppingCart cart;

      @Inject
      void setShoppingCart(ShoppingCart cart) {
         this.cart = cart;
      }
   }
   ```
3. Field injection:

   ```
   public class Checkout {
      private @Inject ShoppingCart cart;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 3):

An opinion-based answer, but it would seem that injecting through the constructor is best for the following reasons.

- You can null check in the constructor, which might save you some error handling elsewhere in your class.
- You can more easily inject mocks into your class for testing.
- You can't forget to supply a dependency.
- It doesn't look like magic.

Comment: I don't think it is really opiniated. Constructor injection is definately your best pick. It prevents [temporal coupling](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/24/DesignSmellTemporalCoupling/) and when your component has [a single constructor](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=97), it prevents your component from requiring a dependency on the DI library itself.

Comment: But most examples with DI is field injection. See here https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/cdi-basic007.htm#GJBAN. Constructor and method parameter injection seem rare from what I saw.

Comment: Field injection in examples is for simplicity. You should avoid using it in real application because of the reasons mentioned by Kenny Hung. But you can use setter, that is the way the spring does.

Answer (score 0):

Field injection is probably the most common. The reason is pretty obvious - it's the fastest way to connect things make it do something.

As for differences, there are some:

- *constructor injection*

  - the only way to access other beans **while you initialize this one**
  - otherwise while instantiating beans, your bean field (*field injection*) will not yet work
  - example: you need data from other beans while creating this one; based on such data you determine for instance what strategy will this bean use for data storage
- *field injection*

  - leads to lazy injection of beans (might be Weld specific, not sure now)
  - means if you don't do any extra work to make it eager, the bean will only actually be accessible once you first invoke a method on it
  - this is a go-to approach if you "just want the bean"
- *initializer method parameter injection*

  - you will want this, if you need some extra work done at the moment you inject the bean
  - this event might happen more than once per bean lifecycle (that's what you have scopes for)
  - example of usage: you might want to fire an event once the injection happens

All in all, you are free to use **any** approach. The story here is that there are some use-cases which couldn't be covered by simple field injection.

This is just from the top of my head and is not exhaustive. I hope it sheds some light on the topic.